# onChange event Is not getting called

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, onchange

I am trying to test the following onChange event- The test is passing but its not getting called right according to jest--coverage

**Using JEST - ENZYME  REACT JS**

There are a total of 4 onChange events and I was able to test the first 2.

Here is the component : The first 2  onChange events are passing :

```
renderBottomPanel = (type) => {
if(type !== 'none'){
  return(
    <div className="bottom-panel">
      <SplitPane split="vertical" minSize={50} maxSize={50} defaultSize={50}>
          <div>
            <a onClick={this.saveChartTemplateToView}>
              <FontAwesome title="Save Chart Template" name='savetemplate' className={'fa-floppy-o no-border fa-floppy-o-override-color'}/>
            </a>
            <a onClick={this.prettyChartTemplate}>
              <FontAwesome title="Format JSON" name='formathtml' className={'fa-list-ul no-border'}/>
            </a>
          </div>
          <SplitPane split="vertical" minSize={300} defaultSize={window.screen.availWidth/2 - 75}>
            <div className="liquid-content-panel">
              <textarea id='chartcontent' name='chartcontent' className='liquid-content-input' type='text' onChange={e => this.setState({viewChartScript:e.target.value})} value={this.state.viewChartScript}/>
            </div>
            <div className="shaped-JSON-panel">
              <textarea id = 'shapedJSON' name='shapedJSON' className='shaped-JSON-input' type='text' onChange={e => this.setState({chartPrototype:e.target.value})} value={JSON.stringify(this.state.chartPrototype, null, 2)} disabled={true}/>
            </div>
          </SplitPane>
      </SplitPane>
    </div>
  )
}
else{
  return(
    <div className="bottom-panel">
      <SplitPane split="vertical" minSize={50} maxSize={50} defaultSize={50}>
          <div>
            <a onClick={this.saveTemplateToView}>
              <FontAwesome title="Save Template" name='savetemplate' className={'fa-floppy-o no-border fa-floppy-o-override-color'}/>
            </a>
            <a onClick={this.prettyTemplate}>
              <FontAwesome title="Format HTML" name='formathtml' className={'fa-list-ul no-border'}/>
            </a>
          </div>
          <SplitPane split="vertical" minSize={300} defaultSize={window.screen.availWidth/2 - 75}>
            <div className="liquid-content-panel">
              <textarea id='liquidcontent' name='liquidcontent' className='liquid-content-input' type='text' onChange={e => this.setState({viewScript:e.target.value})} value={this.state.viewScript}/>
            </div>
            <div className="shaped-JSON-panel">
          //    <textarea  name='shapedJSON' className='shaped-JSON-input' type='text' onChange={e => this.setState({cleanJSON:e.target.value})} value={this.state.cleanJSON} disabled={true}/>
            </div>
          </SplitPane>
      </SplitPane>
    </div>
  )
}
```

}

This is what i have for my test. I wrote the setup for the first 2 and they are working.

working

```
    it(" RenderBottomPanel method : should test onChange event on chart content :", () => {
baseProps.onChange.mockClear();
wrapper.setState({
    viewChartScript:'test-id'
    });
wrapper.update()
wrapper.find('#chartcontent').simulate('change',{target: {value: 'testing'}} )
expect(wrapper.state().viewChartScript).toEqual('testing');
});
```

failing

```
it(" RenderBottomPanel method : should test onChange event on liquidcontent :", () => {
  baseProps.onChange.mockClear();
  wrapper.setState({
    viewScript:'test-id'
    });

 wrapper.update()

wrapper.find('#liquidcontent').simulate('change',{target: {value: 'testing'}} )
expect(wrapper.state().viewScript).toEqual('testing');
});
```

Thanks: Goal is to get this test passing and simulate change correctly

Comment: Would help if you included the tests that do work and your whole component, stripped down to the relevant parts.

Comment: the test that works is exactly the same set up - what changes is the id# and setState

Comment: @dan-klasson updated: i added the code +  a working test and a failing test

Comment: So if you change the `liquidcontent` part in the `wrapper.find`, does it fail then?

Comment: yeah . i tried class name as well

Comment: if it fails when you change it, it's clearly being called by your test then. so the coverage tool has a bug in it. you could split the `if(type !== 'none')` part into two arrow functions and see if that helps.

Comment: No its not finding the element -  i get the following :  Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead. I tried to find by classname and by id

Comment: so how are you calling `renderBottomPanel`? should all be hinging on that